# Trying to access element of a matrix

Tags: dynamic, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about MapThread and Dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5817/question-about-mapthread-and-dynamic)

I'm trying to extract element of a matrix. Let's suppose that the matrix is

```
ACC = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 3}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

then

```
ACC[[1,4]]
```

will return 3. 
I don't understand why Mathematica is giving me the error Part::partw when trying to get the value [[1,x]] with x>1 of the following matrix Rbar:  (sorry for the code but it wont work otherwise)

```
Avz[\[Theta]z_, 
   dz_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]z], -Sin[\[Theta]z], 0, 0}, {Sin[\[Theta]z], 
    Cos[\[Theta]z], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, dz}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

Avx[\[Theta]x_, 
   dx_] := {{1, 0, 0, dx}, {0, Cos[\[Theta]x], -Sin[\[Theta]x], 
    0}, {0, Sin[\[Theta]x], Cos[\[Theta]x], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

Linea[tz_, dz_, tx_, dx_] := Avz[tz, dz].Avx[tx, dx];

Grid[{{"", "Theta", "d", "Alpha", "a"}, {"Link1", 
   InputField[Dynamic[t1], FieldSize -> 3], 
   InputField[Dynamic[d1], FieldSize -> 2], 
   InputField[Dynamic[alpha1], FieldSize -> 4], 
   InputField[Dynamic[x1], FieldSize -> 1]}}, 
 Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], Alignment -> {{Left, {Center}}}]


Rt = {{1, 0, 0, -L1/2}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

Rbar = Dynamic[Linea[t1, d1, alpha1, x1].Rt]
```

here Rbar[[1,4]] for example returns error, but why?

Comment: hi @narutov6, don't forget that MMA is case sensitive. You use `ACC` and `Acc`. It's a good practice to use all user function as lower case to avoid conflict.

Comment: With your matrix `ACC[[1,3]]` is `0`, not `3`.

Comment: The reason why `Rbar[[1,4]]` does  work the way you expect is because of the incorrect use of `Dynamic` in `Rbar`.

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I troubleshoot when I get a Part::partd or a Part::partw error?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5)

Comment: @rm-rf I'd say it's a duplicate of a question where someone tried using `Dynamic` in a similar incorrect way. I was just trying to find it, but no luck so far.

Comment: @Szabolcs Here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15090/5

Comment: [Jens's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18276/12) on your earlier question should solve this one too: "The Dynamic should wrap the expresion you want to *display*"

Comment: In addition to the above if you are using `Dynamic` and not extracting what you expect then try wrapping your expression in `FullForm` to see what you are actually operating on.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121

Comment: Thank you solved using:
`Rbar = Linea[t1, d1, alpha1, x1].Rt;

d=Dynamic[Rbar[[1,4]]];`
Thanks